# Can X25519 (mult with basepoint) be reversed?

Tags: x25519

I admit I don't know a lot about the math behind Curve25519 and the DH exchange based on it.

I'm asking if after publishing the result of this operation:

```
ephemeral_share = X25519(ephemeral_secret, BASEPOINT)
```

Can `ephemeral_secret` be found by whomever obtains `ephemeral_share`, given that they know the used curve (and therefore the curve's base point)?

It's not that I don't trust Filippo's judgment (the above is taken from a 2019 entry on his blog); I'm just trying to make sure I understand things correctly.

Answer (score 3):

> Can the *ephemeral_secret* be found by whomever obtains the *ephemeral_share*, given that they know the curve that was used (and therefore the curve's basepoint)?

If the design goals of the X25519 implementation at hand are met, and *ephemeral_secret* was generated randomly and kept secret, no. That would be breaking the [Discrete Logarithm Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm) as it stands for X25519.